# Unresolved reference to Transformations

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-lifecycle

I get this error if I do any of the following upgrades:

- `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.0-alpha04` -> `alpha05`
- `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0-alpha01` -> `alpha02`
- `androidx.navigation:navigation-...- ktx:2.6.0-alpha04` -> `alpha05`

For reference I have these dependencies:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```

where `lifecycle_version` is 2.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `myData.map {}`or `myData.switchMap`

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75465435/unresolved-reference-transformations-after-upgrading-lifecycle-dependency)